Jest/supertest returns duplicated data from postgres even thought the result set is unique
I have an API endpoint that takes a client ID and returns its info
Inside, express+typescript calls the Postgres function and returns JSON.
If I run the call by any other means but supertest, the results are correct, and I get one result per unique row (the ID has the constraint). But if I run the test with Jest/Supertest,
the returned results are duplicated - postgress returns two identical rows in JSON array. If I use the row_to_json function, it errors out with error: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression, even though it should never happen
Is there a bug with supertest?

Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
